# How to implement NSFetchedResultsController delegate when multiple row is on deletion?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Two items is deleted.

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject!, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    switch(type) {
    case .Delete:

        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

At deletion line I get this error:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught
>   during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an
>   observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification. 
>   Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with
>   userInfo (null)
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to 'batch' the updates by also implementing the `controllerWillChangeContent` and `controllerDidChangeContent` delegate methods as follows (although sorry these are Obj-c):

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```